# Lua interprets integer as non-integer number

Tags: lua, numbers, integer, division

For some reason Lua doesn't interpret integers as integers if I do the following: (`integer%1` should be `0` but in this example I'll show it is actually

```
x = 4
for i=1,25 do
  x = x - 0.04
end

print(x) -- 3
print(x%1) -- 1
print(math.ceil(x) == x) --false
print(math.ceil(x)) -- 3
```

Probably it is a bug, but is there a way to evade it? this is really important to me. (and no, I can't use `math.ceil(x)` because I have in the way numbers such as `2.4` that I don't want to interpret as integers...

Comment: a hint: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2004/12/27/332974.aspx

Comment: He was trying to teach you how to copy and paste from cmd instead of using screenshots. For your question though try `print(("%0.15f"):format(x))` on your resulting x value and see what you get. That and missingno's answer should show you your problem.

Comment: As http://lua-users.org/wiki/NumbersTutorial clearly says: In the interest of simplicity Lua supports only one type of number, floating point numbers. Thus, @missingno's answer is the perfect solution for you.

Comment: Check out the working draft for Lua 5.3, it introduces an integer type: http://www.lua.org/work/doc/#changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a Lua specific problem and almost every other programming language is going to exhibit similar behaviour.

[Floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) are only able to precisely represent multiples of powers of two (this also includes integers). Since 0.04 (1/25) is not a power of two, your intermediate values (including 2.4) are not able to be precisely represented by floating point numbers so there will be some small roundoff error. They will look all right when you print them because the printing algorithm writes down the nearest decimal but the internal representation will *not* be exactly 2.4

I would suggest refactoring your programs to use integers instead of fractional numbers. For your internal representation, keep everything multiplied by 25 (so 2.4 would be 60), and increment and decrement by 1 instead of 0.04. When you actually need to use the values you can divide them by 25 to get the inexact floating point representation.

BTW, try printing `x-3`. This will reveal that `x` is slightly smaller than `3`

Comment: so the only way to get 3 out of 4 in 25 iterations is to do multiply everything by 100 and than dividing it by 100? oh that's bad for me..

Comment: @user3050072: The other alternative would be to stop using equality comparisons and the mod operator and start using more fuzzy approximations (for example, instead of testing if two numbers are equal, test if they are very close to each other). However, if you can manage to work with precise integers then there is much less  things to worry about. You could also use a [decimal number luibrary](http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/#ldecnumber) but thats probably overkill.

Comment: @user3050072 This assumes that your Lua implements the `number` data type in floating point. Indeed, the source code uses `double` by default but the source code can be built with other implementations. The language doesn't require much of `number`.